# Android: security exception with launchMode="singleTask"

Tags: android, security, exception, launchmode

I have declared the launch mode of my activity to be singleTask. If I
launch my application, press the home button, go to an email client
(gmail in this case) & preview an attachment using my application, I
am experiencing a security exception on Android versions 2.3 & later,
which says that I do not have the permissions to access gmail
attachments. The exception does not occur on prior versions & if I do
not use singleTask as the launchMode.

The exception occurs on this line-

```
mContext.getContentResolver().openInputStream(intent.getData());
```

where mContext is the activity context.

Is this a known issue?

Any help will be really appreciated.

Thanks,

Akshay

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had posted this on Android-developers and got this response from Dianne Hackborn-

"Sorry, this is probably a bug in 2.3 with trying to grant a URI permission to an activity instance that is already running. I'll look in to this. In the mean-time, the only solution may be to not use singleTask for the activity being launched to a preview an attachment. This is actually the preferred thing to do, since your preview activity should be running as its own instance as part of the gmail task."

Answer (score 0):

The problem might happen because the called intent's activity in the 2.3 implementation does not fit the `launchMode:"standard"` or `launchMode:"singleTop"` requirement stated in the [android:launchMode description](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#lmode).

But it would be also useful to take a look at [this issue: Behaviour of launchMode=“singleTask” not as described](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=11160). It is scary, hopefully your problem isn't rooted there, and can be solved within the current versions.

Comment: Thanks rekaszeru! I had posted this on Android-developers and got this response from Dianne Hackborn- Sorry, this is probably a bug in 2.3 with trying to grant a URI permission to an activity instance that is already running.  I'll look in to this.  In
the mean-time, the only solution may be to not use singleTask for the activity being launched to a preview an attachment. This is actually the preferred thing to do, since your preview activity should be running as its own instance as part of the gmail task.

Comment: I'm glad you've got the answer, please post it here (quoting as you've got from Dianne), and 48 hours after your post, you can accept it, so all the people who have the same issue can find the answer too. thanks a lot!